# Scala specs2 matcher for a File's extension

Tags: scala, matcher, specs2

I'm trying to create a specs2 matcher that asserts the validity of a `File` extension (by reusing the existing `endWith` matcher). However I get a type error. How could I get around it?

```
import java.io.File
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.matcher.{ Expectable, Matcher }

class SampleSpec extends Specification {
  def hasExtension(extension: => String) = new Matcher[File] {
    def apply[S <: File](actual: Expectable[S]) = {
      actual.value.getPath must endWith(extension)
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the compiler error:

```
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult[java.lang.String]
 required: org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult[S]
             actual.value.getPath must endWith(extension)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use the `^^` operator (taking inspiration from the parser combinators operators) and simply write:

```
def hasExtension(extension: =>String) = endWith(extension) ^^ ((_:File).getPath)
```

For reference the various ways of creating custom matchers are presented [here](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#Custom).

Comment: Thanks! I like the conciseness of it. Is there no operator that does the same but with the arguments swapped? I think it would be a bit more clear as to what it does.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. You can now do it with the latest 1.12-SNAPSHOT: def haveExtension(extension: =>String) = ((_:File).getPath) ^^ endWith(extension)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've got it working by using the `^^` operator which adapts between matcher types. It looks like a functor's map function to me.

```
def hasExtension(extension: => String) = new Matcher[File] {
  def apply[S <: File](actual: Expectable[S]) = {
    actual must endWith(extension) ^^ ((file: S) => file.getPath)
  }
}
```